# Why does Java exit with success after an uncaught exception?

Tags: java, exceptions

Any time a Perl, Python, C++ or Tcl program halts with an unhandled exception, those language runtimes take care to register a non-zero exit code for the process. Even Eclipse-based programs return 1 if they fail during startup. Programs run by the standard `java.exe`, however, happily return zero no matter how abruptly they end, unless the program calls `System.exit()` with an exit value. Even `AssertionFailedError` or `UnsatisfiedLinkError` are reported back to the calling program as successful exits.

Of course not all systems have program return codes, but Unix and Windows were important enough to warrant `java.lang.Process.exitValue()` for child processes; don't they also warrant honouring conventions for parent processes?

Is this a flaw in the language design or just in the implementation? Is there an argument that it's a good idea?

Comment: Wonder if this is not better suited on StackOverflow... Just an opinion, though.

Comment: @gablin Mmm, indeed I started writing this question on SO then changed my mind and posted it here.

Comment: The `java` command in [Java 6](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/91e5cc5d33b9/src/share/tools/launcher/java.c#l604) and [Java 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/tools/launcher/java.c#l604) both seem to respond with a non-zero exit code if an uncaught exception is raised.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the Java Language Specification does not explicitly define what exit value to expect, then it is *undefined* and you should not rely on it.

You need to catch Throwable in your main method, and call System.exit(1) yourself.

Comment: So isn't it a shortcoming to leave it undefined?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  The only important thing is what the JLS says.

Comment: The JLS isn't the only relevant contract, though it is the dominant one.